# Array of objects from array passing test

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray of objects, which have a property `id`.

I then have another NSArray with a selection of ids.

I need to get all the objects in the first array which have the ids listed in the second array.

Is it possible to do this without for loops (well 1 for loop is ok, but I'd like to avoid it). I know how to do this with 2 for loops, but this seems very inefficient. So basically I'm looking for the most efficient way.

(The Id is an NSURL btw, so it can't be anything integer specific)

Comment: Even with big arrays, loops should not take much time. What's taking time I guess is comparing objects... Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No loops!

```
NSArray *arrayOfIdentifiers = ...;
NSArray *arrayOfObjects = ...;
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", arrayOfIdentifier];
NSArray *filteredObjects = [arrayOfObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Well, no loops that you write.  There are probably loops inside `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

Comment: I figured that loops I write are going to be less efficient somehow, than loops inside an existing method? Thanks :)

Comment: @Jonathan. not necessarily... a `for` loop has the same efficiency whether you write it or Apple writes it. The real thing here is that if Apple has already written code that does what you need, there's no need for you to re-write it.

Comment: Good point. Btw there is a stray double quote at the end of the 3rd line.

Answer (score 2):

You need an intersection os sets.

```
NSMutableSet *set1=[[[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:array1] autorelease];
NSMutableSet *set2=[[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:array2];
[set1 intersectSet:set2];
[set2 release];
NSArray *newArray=[set1 allObjects];
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add I need to keep the order.